# Access $stateParams of new state in service called from resolve function with UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to access `$stateParams` for the state you're transitioning to from a service called in a resolve function? With `ngRoute` you'd use `$route.current.params`. As this minimal plunk shows, the service only sees the state you're leaving:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QpwgAj?p=preview

I get the new `$stateParams` when `$stateParams` is injected directly into a resolve function, but the values are still behind by one route in the service.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything.  Until the transition is complete, the $stateParams service doesn't have the new params.

Comment: Is there any way to access params from the new state before the transition is complete with the `$state` (or some other) service?

Comment: As i see in the indepth state documentation there is a sample code, that shows `$stateParams` being injected into the resolve hash. See wiki section `Resolve` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: A good thought. I have read that page. As I said in my question, I am able to access `$stateParams` when `$stateParams` is injected directly into a resolve function (which is what the examples show). I'm looking for a way to access them from a service. I know I can inject `$stateParams` into a resolve function and pass that value to a service. Is that the best/preferred way to get the effect I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **can't inject** the the incoming parameters into the service itself, but you can **pass them to a function** in the service (or you could also **assign them to a property in the service**).

[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysnkqe?p=preview) shows how to pass them to a function, which in turns stores them to a property in the service.  Using a "dummy" property shouldn't hurt, but it is a bit ugly. :)

It might make more sense to pass the parameters to the controller as a resolve property and then hand them out to a service from the controller constructor... that's what I'd do.

Comment: Hi, your plunker was broken so I fixed it, updated fork here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JZjkG1UdTi1V60DykFxg?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

In your resolve function in stateprovider

```
resolve: {
    something: function(MyService, $stateParams){
        return MyService.doSomethingWithParam($stateParams.someParameter);
    }
}
```

In your service

```
myService = angular.module('myService', [])
    .factory('MyService', function() {

        var myServiceInstance;

        myServiceInstance.doSomethingWithParam= function(param){
            //...store or do something with your state param here and return result
        };

        return myServiceInstance;
});
```

Comment: @pilau, if you use `ng-annotate` there will be no problem with minification.