# Can I pass data to a state with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this call to a state:

```
self.$state.go('heat',
                {
                    subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
                    examId: self.exs.exam.examId,
                    testId: self.test.testId,
                    questionNumber: 1
                })
```

Is there a way that I can pass an array of data to this state and if so how could I get that data in my router config file?

Comment: Depends how much of that you want in the actual URL versus using a service to store some of it

Answer (score 1):

As the answer by Mike suggests, you can add `params` in the config. I'd just like to elaborate on that.

In your `app.js`, you should specify the parameters you are sending

```
.state('statename',{
        url:'/state',
        templateUrl:'js/apps/xPage/templates/something.html',
        params:{'parameter1':null,'parameter2':null},
        controller:'stateCtrl'

    });
```

In your `controller`, you can define your data like this

```
 $scope.parameter1=[];
 $scope.parameter2=[];
```

You can add to your array like this

```
$scope.parameter1.push(x);
$scope.parameter2.push(y);
```

Finally, send your values like this

```
$state.go('results',{'parameter1':$scope.parameter1,'parameter2':$scope.parameter2});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When I do a $state.go() is it possible to also send no parameters in one place of my code and then for another place of my code do a $state.go() with parameters.  I was also thinking to send a large array as a parameter. Do you think that would be okay? Finally one more question, can I get the value of the params inside the resolve? I would like to use them there. If you could show an example that would be very good.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it'll be an issue to send a large array. Also, if you think things might get too cluttered, go with using a `service` or a `factory` to move around data.Also, I [don't think you can get the values of the params inside the resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565221/access-stateparams-of-new-state-in-service-called-from-resolve-function-with-ui).Could you please clarify on the `send no parameters in one place...`, didn't really understand that.

Comment: I have a few different places in code where I do a $state.go.  In some scripts I want to send params and in others no params.  Just wondering if that is okay.

Comment: One more thing I am confused about.  I already pass parameters with the URL but now I want to pass some none URL params also. Can you give me an example of how I could do this using the $state.go in the question. Thanks

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr by any chance with basic functionality?I'll try and see if i can incorporate this into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `params` in the state config, and specify the values in `$state.go`. You can then access these values with `$stateParams` service.

[UI Router Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state)