# ui-router pass URL query parameters to controller via service - $stateParams values 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router and attempting to pass URL query parameters to the controller in the `.config` of the module, using a `.service` that has been injected into the `resolve` argument of the `.state` definition.

**Preferred Method - (not working reliably)**

```
.state('list', {
    url: '/list?country&state&city',
    templateUrl: "list.html",
    controller : 'myController',
    resolve: {
          currentUrlTypeParam : ['myServices', function(myServices){        // object variable that can be injected into specified controller
              return myServices.getUrlTypeParams();
            }]
        }
  })
```

While the documentation says that only Constant and Provider recipes can be injected into the `.config` function of a module, I'm following [this method of injecting a `.service` into the `resolve` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15938130/3092596) of the `.state` definition.

The reason I'm using a service is that I have a number of states with the same URL query parameters - so it makes sense to write the function once as a service provider rather than repeating it.

I'm using `resolve` rather than just injecting `$stateParams` directly into the controller so that I can complete server calls during config.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBnHj0NYKMNP3UGfo7O4?p=preview) of this (showing 3 possible states with the same URL parameters) - however it doesn't work reliably - the correct URL params seem to arrive on a 2nd click to a different URL in the same state.

Even more frustrating is that while the `$stateParams` seems to arrive correctly (on 1st click) in the `.service` function - but the values come up as `undefined` when trying to access them - check out the plunker `console.log` to see this strange phenomena !

eg
`console.log` will output `$stateParams` in the `.service` function as:
`{country: "US", state: undefined, city: undefined}`
however when I call `$stateParams.country` within the function i get `undefined` ??

**Alternative Messier Method - (working fine)**

The alternative is repeating the same large `.service` code within the `resolve` argument of *every state definition* - which works reliably, but bloats the code (...and this is a simplified example of the states / params I am dealing with).

```
.state('list', {
    url: '/list?country&state&city',
    templateUrl: "list.html",
    controller : 'myController',
    resolve: {
        currentUrlTypeParam : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            var urlTypeParameter = {}                                                                               // define an object that we'll return as the value for $scope.loadMethodParameters
            if($stateParams.country && typeof $stateParams.country !== undefined){
                urlTypeParameter.type = 'country';
                urlTypeParameter.parameter = $stateParams.country;
            } else if($stateParams.state && typeof $stateParams.state !== undefined){
                urlTypeParameter.type = 'state';
                urlTypeParameter.parameter = $stateParams.state;
            } else if($stateParams.city && typeof $stateParams.city !== undefined){
                urlTypeParameter.type = 'city';
                urlTypeParameter.parameter = $stateParams.city;
            } else {
                urlTypeParameter.type = 'default';
            }
            return urlTypeParameter;
        }]
    }
})
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/82FaMyaY25eJ4j5NUDdM?p=preview) for a rather ...inelegant way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your service doesn't work is because you are trying to inject `$stateParams`, rather than passing it into the service function itself.

Rather than injecting `$stateParams` into your service and running `return myServices.getUrlTypeParams();`, try passing `$stateParams` into your service functions. For example:

```
resolve: {
    currentUrlTypeParam : ['$stateParams', 'myServices', function($stateParams, myServices){        // object variable that can be injected into specified controller
        return myServices.getUrlTypeParams($stateParams);
    }]
}
```

Then you will have to modify your service to **not** inject `$stateParams`, but instead pass it into your service function:

```
this.getUrlTypeParams = function($stateParams){ ... }
```

Comment: thanks i'll give this a go - how is it that using my 'preferred' method `$stateParams` arrives perfectly within the service, but its values can't be accessed ?

Comment: It could be because of *when* $stateParams is updated. Anyway while $stateParams could be considered an injectable module throughout an app, it really should only be injected in a controller or a resolve, and nowhere else.

Comment: Actually, I just realised it is because you are logging the $stateParams object. Whenever you call `console.log()` what you see is not the object at the time of the log, but rather at the time of viewing the object in the console. So it may appear that the values are there and have been updated, when in fact they haven't. You can see this by instead of logging the whole params object, simply log one of the children like, `console.log($stateParams.country)`

Comment: yes you're right - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565594/3092596 - I've updated the original plunker if you want to include it in your answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnERL1OsopHopXiLXJC5?p=preview